# How to remove frame from ggtheme

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some data using ggplot. Also, I'm using the gdocs theme from the ggthemes package.

```
library(ggthemes)
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
g <- ggplot(data, aes (x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
g + theme_gdocs()
```

[image: gdocs theme]

I want to use this theme, but without the border that surrounds the whole plot, similar to the default theme.

```
g
```

[image: default theme]

Which settings should I modify to achieve this?

This is the first time I play with other themes in ggplot so I may be missing something simple, but I can't get it to work on my own. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `+ theme(plot.background=element_blank())`

Answer (score 2):

Posting solution from above provided by hrbrmstr:

Use `plot.background=element_blank()` in a call to `theme`:

```
library(ggthemes)
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
g <- ggplot(data, aes (x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
g + theme_gdocs() + theme(plot.background=element_blank())
```

From the ggplot2 [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html):

> Use `theme()` to modify individual components of a theme, allowing you to control the appearance of all non-data components of the plot. theme() only affects a single plot: see theme_update() if you want modify the active theme, to affect all subsequent plots.
>
> ...
>
> `plot.background`: background of the entire plot (element_rect; inherits from rect)

This applies to any plot created using `ggplot2`, of course, not just those using `theme_gdocs()`.